# Javascript inherited class constructor issue

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, prototype

I want to create a subclass from a superclass using prototypes in javascript, so I set them up:

```
var SuperClass = function() {
    this.a = 1;
    this.get = function() {return this.a;}
    this.init = function() {
        CreateStrangeThings();
    }
    this.init();
}
var SubClass = function() {
    this.b = 2;
    this.get = function() {return this.b;}
}
SubClass.prototype = new SuperClass();
```

The problem is, the line `SubClass.prototype = new SuperClass();` calls the `CreateStrangeThings();` function. I want this function to be called only when I **create** the subclass object (`var subOjbect = new SubClass();`)

How to overcome this issue? Maybe I should use `SubClass.prototype = SuperClass;` ? Is it wise?

**EDIT:**

```
SubClass.prototype = SuperClass;
```

removes "a" property from SubClass

Comment: So why don't you include the `CreateStrangeThings()` function in the `SubClass` constructor?

Comment: "CreateStrangeThings()" must be initiated in every base class in my application design and should not be repeated in coding (true OOP)

Comment: `SubClass.prototype = SuperClass` will make nothing but your `SubClass.prototype` a function. Avoid that. Also watch that you are shadowing your `get` function in the prototype chain, which is expected to return `this.a` by the `get` function in the instantiated object which returns `this.b`. Besides, what exactly does `CreateStrangeThings()` do..?

Comment: Something that shouldn't be done upon setting up the base class. (it creates graphics)

Comment: Btw, you should not use an `init` method that you call from your constructor. Instead, put the code directly in the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is, the line `SubClass.prototype = new SuperClass();` calls the `CreateStrangeThings();` function.

Yes. That's why that pattern, despite being often-cited, is wrong. Another reason is that it ignores the possibility the superclass constructor may require arguments.

Instead, create the prototype object without calling the super constructor:

```
SubClass.prototype = Object.create(SuperClass.prototype);
SubClass.prototype.constructor = SubClass;
```

...and also call the super constructor inside `SubClass`:

```
var SubClass = function() {
    SuperClass.call(this);
    this.b = 2;
    this.get = function() {return this.b;}
};
```

So all together we get:

```
var SuperClass = function() {
    this.a = 1;
    this.get = function() {return this.a;}
    this.init = function() {
        CreateStrangeThings();
    }
    this.init();
};
var SubClass = function() {
    SuperClass.call(this);
    this.b = 2;
    this.get = function() {return this.b;}
};
SubClass.prototype = Object.create(SuperClass.prototype);
SubClass.prototype.constructor = SubClass;
```

---

Or of course, use ES2015 and a transpiler.

```
class SuperClass {
    constructor() {
        this.a = 1;
        this.get = function() {return this.a;};
        this.init = function() {
            CreateStrangeThings();
        };
        this.init();
    }
}
class SubClass {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.b = 2;
        this.get = function() {return this.b;};
    }
}
```

---

> How to overcome this issue? Maybe I should use `SubClass.prototype = SuperClass;` ? Is it wise?

No. If you want objects created via `new SubClass` to inherit properties from `SuperClass.prototype`, you need `SubClass.prototype` to use `SuperClass.prototype` as its prototype. `SuperClass` doesn't; the prototype of `SuperClass` is `Function.prototype`, not `SubClass.prototype`. (Ignore the name of the `prototype` property on functions; it isn't their prototype, it's the prototype `new` assigns to objects created via `new TheFunction`.)

Comment: @marirena: Yes, it's wrong. I've added a note at the end above.